# Special cosine between scipy sparse matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to compute the cosine similarity of two vectors. These two vectors (call them Ri and Rj) are users' ratings about item i and j, so naturally they are sparse (because typically only a few users would rate a specific item). These vectors have 50000 rows and only 0.1 percent is non-zero.

The cosine similarity should involve co-rated user rating. For instance, if Ri and Rj are two scipy.sparse.csc matrix, and their values are

Ri = [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4]
Rj = [ 0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2]

then co-rated ratings are

Ri' = [ 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4]
Rj' = [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2]

so the cosine similarity should be

inner(Ri', Rj') / (|Ri'| * |Rj'|)

My question is, is there an efficient (preferably **non-looping**) way to calculate for which entry both matrix have non-zero value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which matrix you're asking about here, but suppose you have the two original arrays in the variables,

```
Ri = [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4]; Rj = [ 0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2]
```

Here's how you can build the co-rated ratings and calculate the cosine similarity,

```
import numpy as np
Rip = np.array( [ i if j != 0 else 0 for i,j in zip(Ri,Rj) ] )
Rjp = np.array( [ j if i != 0 else 0 for i,j in zip(Ri,Rj) ] )
```

If you don't want to explicitly use a for statement you can use a map,

```
Rip = map( lambda x,y: 0 if y == 0 else x, Ri, Rj )
Rjp = map( lambda x,y: 0 if x == 0 else y, Ri, Rj )
```

Then the cosine similarity can be calculated with these explicit (or dense) representations of `Rip` and `Rjp`

```
cos_sim = float( np.dot( Rip, Rjp ) ) / np.sqrt( np.dot( Rip,Rip ) * np.dot( Rjp,Rjp ) )
```

If you don't want to explicitly store the full arrays you can use `scipy.sparse` to store the vectors as sparse single row (column) matrices.  Note that if you do that `np.dot` will no longer work and you should use the `dot` method of the [sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# make single column/row sparse matrix reps of Rip
row = np.array( [ i for (i,x) in enumerate(Rip) if x != 0 ] )
col = np.zeros( row.size, dtype=np.int32 )
dat = np.array( [ x for (i,x) in enumerate(Rip) if x != 0 ] )
Rip_col_mat = csr_matrix( (dat,(row,col) ) )
Rip_row_mat = csr_matrix( (dat,(col,row) ) )

# make single column/row sparse matrix reps of Rjp
row = np.array( [ i for (i,x) in enumerate(Rjp) if x != 0 ] )
col = np.zeros( row.size, dtype=np.int32 )
dat = np.array( [ x for (i,x) in enumerate(Rjp) if x != 0 ] )
Rjp_col_mat = csr_matrix( (dat,(row,col) ) )
Rjp_row_mat = csr_matrix( (dat,(col,row) ) )
```

Now to calculate the cosine similarity we can do,

```
inner = Rip_row_mat.dot( Rjp_col_mat ).data
Rip_m = np.sqrt( Rip_row_mat.dot( Rip_col_mat ).data )
Rjp_m = np.sqrt( Rjp_row_mat.dot( Rjp_col_mat ).data )

cos_sim = inner / ( Rip_m * Rjp_m )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was wondering if there's any way to avoid explicit loop?

Comment: at some level any array operation is going to loop over the elements in some fashion.  `map` can be used if you don't want the "explicit" for loops in the list comprehensions.